# Sed regular expression not matching in configuration

Tags: regex, sed

I have a configuration file where I am trying to replace a particular piece of text. The regex isn't matching though.

Sample config text:

```
containers:
  - name: container-name
    image: docker-registry.prod.com:5000/project:5f9775ae7580e5c06b8c929b91501f722c5d6d99
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

I'm trying to match and replace the `project:<sha>` text.

What I've been tring (using `###` for the sample):

`sed -i '' 's|\/project\:[a-z0-9]+|\/###|g' manifest.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `+` (one or more repetition operator), you need to enable the *extended regular expression* matching (ERE) with `-E` flag (or `-r` in GNU `sed`). By default `sed` will use BRE:

```
sed -E -i '' 's|/project:[a-z0-9]+|/###|g' manifest.yml
```

Also, when using alternative separator in `s` command (here `|`), you don't need to escape the slash (nor colon).